# Insert into select only inserts one row on initial run but is fine each time afterwards

Tags: php, mysql, curl, cron

basically I am using php and mysql to extend the functionality of a mailing client, data is sent over to my server using curl and then inputted into table A in my database, I then select all of the data from table A when it matches today's date and insert it into table B if the dates match like so:

```
$date = $_POST['dateAdded'];
        $today = date("Y-m-d");

        if ($date === $today) {

            $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql="INSERT INTO `$tableB` (`$fields`) SELECT * FROM $tableA WHERE date_Added='$today'";
            $link->exec($sql);
```

There is other code that is ran within this IF statement but I do not feel it is relevant to the question. I know there are other issues with this code such as not escaping post values etc but that is something I am going to tackle in the near future. The problem is that whenever this code is run as part of a cron job it only inserts one row into $tableB but when I clear tableB and one value matching $today from tableA and re-run the code it works everytime (i.e. if I run it manually), the only time it doesn't work is through the cron job. If there is any more code that is needed I am happy to provide it and any help is welcome.

The cron job is run using curl as the data is on a different server.

Could this be to do with the way curl is sending data initially through the cron?
Or is it a problem with the SQL statement itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this statement did lie with the way I was using `$today` but not in the way described above. The problem was solved with a change to the MySQL statement that inserts the data into the database:

**This:**

`$sql="INSERT INTO`$tableB`(`$fields`) SELECT * FROM $tableA WHERE date_Added='$today'";`

**Needed to be changed to this:**

`$sql="INSERT INTO`$tableB`(`$fields`) SELECT * FROM $table WHERE date_Added between '$date_24_hours' AND '$today'";`

Where `$date_24_hours` is this: `$date_24_hours = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today . ' -1 day'));`

There is a need for a comparison between the two dates here otherwise the cron job gets confused with itself and feels it has completed after the first insert completes. Just thought I would share the knowledge since my problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

be carefull, is de date_Added a date field or timestamp? in MySQL, is not the same, because your  date("Y-m-d") against a timestamp is gonna be messed up and problably there lies your problem

try to change

```
$today = date("Y-m-d")
```

TO

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

with the info you give it's the only thing that comes to mind

Comment: It is a date field and works fine when it is run manually so I doubt this will change anything in terms of functionality.

Comment: have you try to see the logs if some info comes up? i don't see any problems in the small code you have here, maybe your trying to see the error in the wrong place mate :)

Comment: the only logs I have access to are the server error logs and there isn't anything within there that cries out to be related to this matter sadly, thanks though.